# how to transform date string from twitter-data into an integer

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I wanted to transform the date string into an integer so I can classify if tweets were made in the morning, midday or evening.

I transformed f.e. the username and location with the encoder, but it doesn't work for the date.

```py
df['user.name'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['user.name'])
df['user.location'] = encoder.fit_transform(df['user.location'])
```

do I need to transform it into 'datetime' first?

[date format from Twitter-data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFaRd.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do it is to convert the date string into datetime first

```py
new_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(twitter_date_string, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

and then use either

```py
new_date.year
new_date.month
new_date.day
new_date.hour
new_date.minute
new_date.second
```

to get what you need as an integer.